# How to keep track of submitted forms in php

Tags: php

I am using Contact Form 7 on my contact page I wonder if there is a way to count the number of times a users submits the form. If this is the code I need to use, where do I insert it?

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'SubmitClick']);"
```

Comment: submit in a db table with two columsn, ID, and columnname, then query the table with COUNT() function for how many values you put in the columnanme. Example; <input type="hidden" value="contactform">...

Comment: That depends on how you want to track this. The code you've shared uses Google Analytics, which is not related to PHP after all. But you could also do this on your own server

Answer (score 0):

find '`form'` tag in your html-code. Then find '`button`' tag with `type='submit'` or `'input'` tag with `type='submit'` and add the above handler to that button element.
Example:

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
...
    <input type='submit' value='Send' onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'SubmitClick']);">
...
</form>
```